# Define a scheme function that computes the trace of a square matrix

Tags: scheme, lisp

> Example
>
> `(trace '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))` should evaluate to 15 (1+5+9).
>   Hint: use `map` to obtain the smaller matrix on which trace can be applied recursively. The Matrix should be squared.

i tried to do it but i cant seem to do it, i tried to get the diagonals first.

```
define (diagonals m n)

(append

(for/list ([slice (in-range 1 (- (* 2 n) 2))])
 (let ((z (if (< slice n) 0 (add1 (- slice n)))))
   (for/list ([j (in-range z (add1 (- slice z)))])
     (vector-ref (vector-ref m (sub1 (- n j))) (- slice j))))
```

is there any way to solve that question in a very simple recursive way using `map`.

i tried to solve it like that.

```
define (nth n l)
(if (or (> n (length l)) (< n 0))
(if (eq? n 0) (car l)
(nth (- n 1) (cdr l)))))
```

`(+ (nth 3 '(3 4 5)) (nth 2 '(3 4 5)) (nth 3 '(3 4 5)))`

but it didnt work too.

Comment: please move your code from comment to question and format it properly. use the "edit" button.

Comment: okay i will do that

Comment: thanks. now please fix parens and indentation and remove the unnecessary comments (and I will remove mine)

Comment: you see, am not a professional in lisp, and so am not good at indentation

Comment: Emacs can indent your code for you in the way we expect you to :-)

Comment: i am going to try it, though i have never heard of Emacs :)

Comment: `(+ (nth 0 '(1 2 3)) (nth 1 '(4 5 6)) (nth 2 '(7 8 9)))` would have worked. (after defining `nth` properly, of course).

Comment: it looks like you copied the code from some place where they intentionally had it written out only partially, with some parts of the code missing. they probably wanted to see if you understand what you are copying. the test was for you to fill in the missing parts in `nth` for example, which you didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(apply + (map (lambda (index row) (list-ref row index))
             '(0 1 2)
             '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))))
```

Of course, turn that into a function.

To handle matrices larger than 3x3, we need more indices.

Since `map` stops when it traverses the shortest of the lists, the `(0 1 2)` list can just be padded out by hand as large as ... your best guess at the the largest matrix you think you would ever represent with nested lists in Scheme before you graduate and never see this stuff again.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think answering homework questions is a good idea in general, I can't resist this because it is an example of both what is so beautiful about Lisp programs and what can be so horrible.

What is so beautiful:

- the recursive algorithm is almost identical to a mathematical proof by induction and it's just so pretty and clever;

What is so horrible:

- matrices are not semantically nested lists and it's just this terrible pun to pretend they are (I'm not sure if my use of `first` & `rest` makes it better or worse);
- it just conses like mad for no good reason at all;
- I'm pretty sure its time complexity is n^2 when it could be n.

Of course Lisp programs do not have to be horrible in this way.

To compute the trace of a matrix:

- if the matrix is null, then the trace is 0;
- otherwise add the top left element to the trace of the matrix you get by removing the first row and column.

Or:

```
(define (awful-trace m)
  (if (null? m)
      ;; the trace of the null matrix is 0
      0
      ;; otherwise the trace is the top left element added to ...
      (+ (first (first m))
         ;; the trace of the matrix without its first row and column which
         ;; we get by mapping rest over the rest of the matrix
         (awful-trace (map rest (rest m))))))
```

And you may be tempted to think the following function is better, but it is just as awful in all the ways described above, while being harder to read for anyone not versed in the auxiliary-tail-recursive-function-with-an-accumulator trick:

```
(define (awful-trace/not-actually-better m)
  (define (awful-loop mm tr)
    (if (null? mm)
        tr
        (awful-loop (map rest (rest mm))
                    (+ tr (first (first mm))))))
  (awful-loop m 0))
```

Comment: lists in Lisp are linear-access, so getting to the diagonal can not be but quadratic. that said, `map` builds top level cons structure anew and so you get quadratic space behaviour; you could go for applying `cdr` *n* times for *nth* row, for constant space (time would still be quadratic of course). Calling `cdr` *n* times for the *nth* row can't be helped, and it's not because Lisp is "awful", but because of data structures used. --- your accumulating code still calls map; all it achieves is avoiding *O(n)* deep stack - not significant, compared to quadratic space and time.

Comment: what am I smoking?! use `nth` of course instead of *n* `cdr`s. it'll still be linear, I think, so quadratic overall. --- OTOH the OP uses `vector-ref`, so maybe their matrices are lists of vectors? this would change things.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, it's quadratic and as you say nothing which computes the trace of such a structure can be better than that (even the OP's technique of making it into vectors, because doing that itself is quadratic).  The accumulator version is demonstrably linear in space assumign a GC or equivalent: it never needs more than n new conses at a time before they become garbage.  I obviously do not think Lisp is awful: I think some programs (in Lisp and other languages) are awful, including this one.

Comment: there was an implied smiley there after the "awful" quote. Should've been explicit! -- as for space linearity of accumulating version: you're right. Was thinking of amount of new conses, so this is more of a time complexity thing. Of course a *Sufficiently Smart Compiler* could just maintain a bunch of pointers into the original structure, with no consing at all. When viewed in that regard, the (first) code becomes a high-level *description*, and *is* beautiful, imho. :)